# How to update/rebuild the index.js of node modules in react native

Tags: react-native, node-modules

There's an index.js in the node module folder that needs updating.  How do you reflect the changes after you have updated it?

Example
node_modules/package/index.js

Edited the js file, but the changes were not reflected even after clearing cache.
Java files were ok.